# Merging two different databases

Tags: mysql, mariadb

For a hobby project, I am populating a database.  At some point, I need to fill missing data from my database, with data I find in another database (if it is there).
In this case, the databases in question are:

```
db1: https://bitbucket.org/jupiter126/simpleveggiegarden/src/main/simpleveggiegarden.sql and<br>

db2: https://www.itis.gov/downloads/itisMySQLTables.tar.gz
```

I could easily do this in bash, by doing 3 queries for every line - but a 100% mariadb (or mysql) way of merging such databases would certainly be much more efficient.

pseudocode would look like:

```
in db1:
select nomen from taxon_Plantae where nomen_en is NULL;
for each $result we get
    in db2:
    select vernaculars.vernacular_name, 
            longnames.completename,vernaculars.language 
    from longnames 
        inner join vernaculars on longnames.tsn=vernaculars.tsn 
    where vernaculars.language='english' 
    and longnames.completename='$result' 
    limit 1;
    if this $result2 is not empty, then
        in db1:
            update taxon_Plantae 
                set nomen_en='$result2' 
            where nomen='$result'
```

Is there a way to implement this completely in mariadb/mysql?

Comment: One of these is MariaDB and one is MySQL? I assume they use different clients, so you'd likely need a script to interface between them anyway, but I'd read relevant records from one (whichever was the smaller dataset, if possible) and just stuff them into a temp table in the other., then update the table there with data from the temp table. Does that work?

Comment: use an update statement; Join on keys between data sets use `coalesce()` to take 1st non-null value.  Assuming one is a master set.  This however assumes a connected/linked/virtual in the final system.

Comment: Actually, the 2 db are completely different, the only common field might be the latin name of the plant ($nomen).